# Adding custom classes to fxml files

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

How can I add a custom class to an fxml file.

I've tried this adding this:

```
package gameName.FinishedClasses;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class CardButton extends Button
{
  int cardID;

  public CardButton(String n , int m)
  {
    setText(n);
    cardID = m;
  }
  public CardButton(int m)
  {
    cardID = m;
  }
  public int getCardID()
  {
    return cardID;
  }
  public void setCardID(int n)
  {
    cardID =n;
  }
  public void setButtonText(String n)
  {
    setText(n);
  }
}
```

Like this:

```
 <CardButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" fx:id="Button1R1C" cardID="0">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
 </CardButton>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gameName.FinishedClasses$CardButton
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
```

It says it's not able to instantiate and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Do you have the correct import in your FXML file?

Comment: @James_D Welcome back to my shinigans, yes I do.

Comment: So is it just a scene builder issue? Does the application run or do you get FXML-related errors when you run it?

Comment: @James_D If I switch it over to a regular button, everything works fine. The issue started when I decided to import the CardButton and replace the Button.

Comment: So is it just a scene builder issue? Does the application run or do you get FXML-related errors when you run it?

Comment: @James_D It doesnt run. FXML related errors.

Comment: So post the stack trace in your question.

Comment: @James_D Heh, maybe it is an import issue? Now im confused, I'm not getting any compiler errors.

Comment: Of course you're not getting any compile errors. FXML is not compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader` expects your class and package names to follow [standard naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Specifically, since `FinishedClasses` is capitalized, the FXML import

```xml
<?import gameName.FinishedClasses.CardButton ?>
```

is interpreted as `CardButton` being an inner class in a class called `FinishedClasses`. Rename your packages correctly (i.e. all lower case) and it should work correctly.

Comment: This should still cause an error, since there is no constructor without parameters and none of the constructor parameters of the other constructors are annotated with `@NamedArg`, but at least it should solve the issue posted in the question...